# submit button on form not working on an include member

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following code in an "include" member... when I click the submit button nothing happens. I tried executing the full URL including the mylogin.htm and it works....What am I doing wrong? Additionally, when I click the "Contact our office!" link nothing happens... what am I doing wrong in this code?

```
<div style="text-align:center">

    <p>MyLogin Test</p>
    <form name="mylogin" method="POST" action="authenticate_to_userpage_db.php">
    <div  width="300px" max-length="100%">
    <label for="userid">User Name:</label><br />
    <input type="text" size="20" name="userid" /><br />
    <label for="password">Password:</label><br />
    <input type="password" size="20" name="user_password" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign In!" /><br />
    </div>
    </form> 
    <font face="Arial" size="2">Forgot Password?</font><br />
    <a href="/forgotpass.php"><u>Contact our office!</u></a><br /> 

</div>
```

MyLogin Test
User Name:

Password:

Forgot Password?
Contact our office!

Comment: Is the authenticate_to_userpage_db.php in the same location as the form when you submit it? A little error checking birdie would've told you. Or, did you just open these files in your browser without using a web server?

Comment: what do you mean by 'nothing happened' open your browser's console and see if in the network something happened.

Comment: The code looks all right, if a bit old fashioned.  (I haven't seen an INPUT tag used for a button in years.  Why aren't you using BUTTON tags?)  Let me suggest you locate your website's log directory and look at the error_log file.  The odds are there's something there that's not percolating up the the browser level.  Log directory locations sometimes change by the software used to manage the domain, but they're usually in mydomain.com/logs.

Comment: Yes, the authenticate_to_userpage_db.php is in same directory as the form(mylogin.htm).... I didn't write this code just trying to make it work... its part of wordpress website...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you "include" something, you have to keep in mind, that it's paths need to be relative to the new executing location.

So, if you have a structure like this:

```
index.php
folder
  - login.html
  - forgotpass.php
  - authenticate_to_userpage_db.php
```

and you are using `include("folder/login.html")` inside `index.php`, the file is executed / interpreted in the root-direcotry. hence the links have to be changed to `folder/forgotpass.php` or `folder/authenticate_to_userpage_db.php`

But at least you should get a 404 and not "nothing happens"? (Or do you mean a 404 by saying "nothing happens"?)

Comment: data/mylogin.htm, data/forgotpass.php and data/authenticate_to_userpage_db.php are in the same directory...when the submit (Sign In!) button is clicked.... nothing happens (no screen or 404 is displayed)....when the Forgot Password link is clicked no message is displayed...

Comment: `its part of wordpress website` then it is ALMOST guaranteed that the execution-location during runtime is NOT `/data/`, hence you need to fix your links inside these subfolder'd files. But since you didn't write the code, there should be a docu on how to implement?

Comment: generelly, everything has to be seen from the "root" directory, if some sort of templating engine is used, cause that's where the invoking `index` file is usually located. So, even if you include `data/login.html` through the wordpress templating engine, links inside that file need to point to `data/authenticate_to_userpage_db.php`, cause the file is included in `/`, hence the correct relativ path during runtime needs the folder(s) in it. (Not a wordpress user, but that's general php/html 1o1 - which wordpress is based on.)

Comment: `I tried executing the full URL including the mylogin.htm and it work` that perfectly matches my idea, cause when you call `http://example.com/data/login.html`, the script runs in `/data` - hence all the relative links pointing to the SAME directory are correct. Running the login file through an index-file (`http://example.com/index.php?mode=login` (or the like)) will run in `/`, hence the relative filepaths need to be `data/whateverfile.ext` - else the script will look for `http://example.com/whateverfile.ext`

Comment: I found that my problem had to with SSL, there was a mixture of 'http://' and 'https://'... I changed everything to "https://" and I was able to get pass my errors...